# De 20 números enteros tengo que determinar los positivos y negativos. Si son positivos debo sacarles promedio

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo hacer para determinar el promedio, es decir: sumar los números positivos para posteriormente sacarle promedio?

Aquí el código:

```
 while(contador<20)
{
    contador++; //aumento mi contador en 1 contador=contador+1

    //proceso de lectura del número
    printf("INGRESO NUMERO %d \n",contador);
    printf("Ingresa un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    //evaluación del numero
    if(numero>=0)
    { //caso numero sea positivo
        positivos=(numero>0);
        sumap=positivos+positivos;
        printf("Tu numero ingresado es positivo. \n");
        promedio=sumap/numero; //aumento mi contador de numeros positivos++;

    }
    else
    { //caso de que sea negativo
        printf("Tu numero ingresado es negativo. \n ");
        suma=suma+numero; //suma acumulada de numeros negativo
        printf("La suma de numeros negativos es de :%d. \n \n",suma);
    }
}//fin del ciclo while
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y porque no los contas, de la misma forma que los sumas?

Comment: Por favor muestra el código completo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que me desconciertan de tu código...

1. La intrucción `positivos=(numero>0);`... ¿Qué quieres conseguir con eso?
2. Con `promedio=sumap/numero; //aumento mi contador de numeros positivos++;` ¿qué quieres conseguir aquí? Normalmente el promedio se obtiene siempre al final, cuando tienes el valor total de la suma de tus datos de entrada y los divides entre los números totales ingresados, por lo que debería ser del tipo `promedio = sumap / contador`, aunque ya te digo que esa instrucción tampoco sería válida por lo que te explico en el paso 3.
3. Si ingresas un número negativo, estás incrementando también la variable `contador`. No sé si es lo que quieres hacer. En caso de que quieras hacer el promedio únicamente de 20 números positivos, deberás decrementar la variable contador (otra opción es únicamente aumentarla dentro de la parte del bucle `if-else` que detecta que el número es positivo.

Te dejo un pseudocódigo de lo que deberías tener. Confío en que podrás realizar tu código en base a eso. Cuéntanos qué tal te ha ido!

**PSEUDOCÓDIGO**

```
while ( contador < 20 )
{
    // Inserta el número
    // IF número positivo 
    {
        // Sumas el número a tu variable acumulativa "sumap"
        // Incrementas la variable de control "contador"
    }
    // ELSE número negativo
    {
        // Dices que es negativo
    }
} // Termina el while

// Sacas el promedio con la ecuación que está en el punto 2.
```

Date cuenta, que como te digo, con este pseudocódigo únicamente vas a contar con número positivos, es decir, vas a tener que ingresar 20 número positivos sí o sí, ya que si metes uno negativo no te va a aumentar tu variable `contador`. En caso de que ingreses 20 números, y luego distingas entre positivos o negativos deberás sacar tu variable `contador` fuera del `if-else` para que independientemente del número que ingreses te vaya aumentando la variable.

Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

El promedio sólo lo puedes calcular cuando tienes la suma total y conoces la cantidad de números a promediar. En tu caso estás "*intentando promediar*" cada vez que encuentras un número positivo:

```
while(contador<20)
{
    ....

    if(numero>=0)
    { //caso numero sea positivo
        positivos=(numero>0);
        sumap=positivos+positivos;
        printf("Tu numero ingresado es positivo. \n");
        promedio=sumap/numero;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- ¿Promedio?
    }
```

Las operaciones ni siquiera están bien, por la redacción de tu pregunta pareces saber que para calcular un promedio debes sumar los números:

> es decir: sumar los números positivos

Pero estás sumando el resultado de la expresión `(numero>0)` (que en este contexto siempre será 1) y dividiendo dicha suma por el número leído (que será un error si es cero, será uno si el número es uno y será cero en el resto de casos.

Probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
int positivos = 0;
int sumap = 0;

// Si conoces la cantidad de iteraciones, usa 'for' en lugar de 'while'
for (int contador = 0; contador != 20; ++contador)
{
    int numero;

    // Puedes unir llamadas consecutivas a 'printf'
    printf("INGRESO NUMERO %d \nIngresa un numero: ", contador);
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    // Una comparación booleana devuelve 0 para falso y 1 para verdadero.
    positivos += (numero >= 0);

    if (numero >= 0)
    {
        sumap += numero; // Acumula el número
        printf("Tu numero ingresado es positivo. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}

printf("Promedio de positivos: %d\n", sumap / positivos);
```